# Should "Foods that spoiled" in "Foods that spoiled could not be shipped far" be replaced by "Foods that spoil"?

Tags: tense, relative-clauses

In *Our Country* by Joan Garland Atkinson, she writes about foods around 1850 in the United States.

> **Foods that spoiled** could not be shipped far, so you could only eat fruits and vegetables that were grown near where you lived.

Considering "**foods that spoiled**" those days and "**foods that spoil**" these days are exactly the same, I think "**foods that spoil**" should be used in the sentence for clarity instead of "**foods that spoiled**". Am I wrong?

Comment: Possibly related: [What would be the difference between past and present tense here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152339/what-would-be-the-difference-between-past-and-present-tense-here)

Comment: Another one: [I didn't know she has (had) a son](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167922/using-past-tense-when-referencing-a-still-true-fact/167929#167929), with [a nice answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/167929/48335).

Comment: Also note that in most stories or narratives in English: "[the events of the plot are depicted as occurring sometime before the current moment or the time at which the narrative was constructed or expressed to an audience.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narration#Past_tense)"

Comment: @CopperKettle, my question is about the sequence of tenses in relative clauses. So, it has more to do with [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152339/what-would-be-the-difference-between-past-and-present-tense-here). I have a question to you.  I'm interested in the quotation from CGEL about aspect in your profile. Could you tell me what page it is?

Comment: Heh. (0: That's a quotation from another authority, namely, ELL user [StoneyB](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb). (0:

Answer (score 1):

*Considering "foods that spoiled" those days and "foods that spoil" these days are exactly the same*

They are not. The perishables from that epoch are long gone. Foods that spoil today may have the same attributes, qualities, and characteristics, but they are not the same exact ... uh ... entities, for lack of a better word.

Comment: "Foods that spoiled" during a 300 mile journey in 1850 don't spoil in the same journey today anymore. Or they may be in a containership in a giant freezer and not spoil anymore. Which is just one more reason to say "Foods that spoiled".